# custom keybindings for less (lesskey)

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, less

the manpage says I can use `$HOME/.lesskey` file to define my own custom keybindings for `less`. It even shows some examples, such as

```
...
n         repeat-search
\en       repeat-search-all
...
q         quit
...
```

but it does not explain how to find syntax for other keys, that are not in the examples

What is the syntax for `F` keys?

How do I bind <kbd>F3</kbd> to `quit` ?

Comment: This has been answered in a more general way: https://superuser.com/questions/1153576/how-to-map-function-keys-in-less